# Javascript code to make animation react to sound file works in Edge but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, audio

I found this code from a YouTube tutorial produced by Adam Khoury from his Analyser Bars Animation HTML5 Audio API JavaScript Tutorial.  Where a music analyser graphic reacts to a sound file
It is from 2013. I have tried to get it to work by updating the code as far as I understand it. I have removed webkit and adjusted the syntax changing some letters to lowercase. It plays fine in the Edge browser but not in Chrome. Obviously, I have missed something, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**HTML code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js.js"></script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mp3_player">

    <div id="audio_box"></div>

    <canvas id="analyser_render"></canvas>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
body{
    background-color: #494545;
}
#mp3_player{
    width: 420px;
    height: 75px;
    background-color:#FAFAFA;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}
audio{
    width: 400px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    }
#analyser_render{

    width: 400px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    }
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = 'Piano_01.mp3';
audio.controls = true;
audio.loop = true;
audio.autoplay = false;
// Establish all variables that your Analyser will use
var canvas, ctx, source, context, analyser, fbc_array, bars, bar_x, bar_width, bar_height;
// Initialize the MP3 player after the page loads all of its HTML into the window
window.addEventListener("load", initMp3Player, false);
function initMp3Player(){
    document.getElementById('audio_box').appendChild(audio);
    context = new AudioContext(); // AudioContext object instance
    analyser = context.createAnalyser(); // AnalyserNode method
    canvas = document.getElementById('analyser_render');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // Re-route audio playback into the processing graph of the AudioContext
    source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio); 
    source.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(context.destination);
    frameLooper();
}
// frameLooper() animates any style of graphics you wish to the audio frequency
// Looping at the default frame rate that the browser provides(approx. 60 FPS)
function frameLooper(){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(frameLooper);
    fbc_array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbc_array);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Clear the canvas
    ctx.fillStyle = '#006600'; // Color of the bars
    bars = 100;
    for (var i = 0; i < bars; i++) {
        bar_x = i * 3;
        bar_width = 2;
        bar_height = -(fbc_array[i] / 2);
        //  fillRect( x, y, width, height ) // Explanation of the parameters below
        ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height, bar_width, bar_height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Chrome you're running into two issues here:

- in the callback handler for the **onload** event you're creating a new `AudioContext()` which is not allowed because playback needs to be triggered by a user interaction like a mouse click
- chrome prevents access to audio files from the local file system. If you look into the console you most likely spot an error like

> Access to audio at ... from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy

To workaround:

- upload your files to a webserver or run from a local webserver.
- instead of catching the onload event to set up your AudioContext, listen for the Audio objects **playing** event and do the initializaion in it's callback handler. This will make sure the AudioContext is created as soon as the audio started playing because the user clicked on the play button.

Here's an example (just click on 'Run code snippet'):

```js
var audio = new Audio();
audio.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
audio.src = 'https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy?quest=http://www.hyperion-records.co.uk/audiotest/3%20Schubert%20String%20Quartet%20No%2014%20in%20D%20minor%20Death%20and%20the%20Maiden,%20D810%20-%20Movement%203%20Scherzo%20Allegro%20molto.MP3';
audio.controls = true;
audio.loop = true;
audio.autoplay = false;
audio.addEventListener("playing", start);
// Establish all variables that your Analyser will use
var canvas, ctx, source, context, analyser, fbc_array, bars, bar_x, bar_width, bar_height;
// Initialize the MP3 player after the page loads all of its HTML into the window
window.addEventListener("load", initMp3Player, false);

function initMp3Player() {
  document.getElementById('audio_box').appendChild(audio);
}
// frameLooper() animates any style of graphics you wish to the audio frequency
// Looping at the default frame rate that the browser provides(approx. 60 FPS)
function frameLooper() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(frameLooper);
  fbc_array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
  analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbc_array);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Clear the canvas
  ctx.fillStyle = '#006600'; // Color of the bars
  bars = 100;
  for (var i = 0; i < bars; i++) {
    bar_x = i * 3;
    bar_width = 2;
    bar_height = -(fbc_array[i] / 2);
    //  fillRect( x, y, width, height ) // Explanation of the parameters below
    ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height, bar_width, bar_height);
  }
}

function start() {
  context = new AudioContext(); // AudioContext object instance
  analyser = context.createAnalyser(); // AnalyserNode method
  canvas = document.getElementById('analyser_render');
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  // Re-route audio playback into the processing graph of the AudioContext
  source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
  source.connect(analyser);
  analyser.connect(context.destination);
  frameLooper();
  audio.removeEventListener("playing", start);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #494545;
}

#mp3_player {
  width: 420px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}

audio {
  width: 400px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#analyser_render {
  width: 400px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="mp3_player">

    <div id="audio_box"></div>

    <canvas id="analyser_render"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Obscure, this is a perfect solution works great, should have come here before pulling the last few hairs from my head. Thanks again not just for the solution but a very clear explanation..

Comment: Glad I could help atataylor. I hope your hair will grow in real soon! By the way, if you think this is the right answer please accept it.

Comment: Yep. Was gonna answer this.. but no need. @obscure Nailed it.